# cdist only between corresponding pairs

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have 2 lists of values (of the same shape),
and a metric (it should work with any metric that can go into the `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` function):

```py
vals_1 = np.array([[0,1], [1,1], [2,1]])
vals_2 = np.array([[0,1], [2,1], [4,1]])
metric = 'euclidean'
```

I would like to calculate the distances between the corresponding pairs of values.

I can do it like so (with a loop):

```py
dists = []
for val_1, val_2 in zip(vals_1, vals_2):
    dists.append(cdist([val_1], [val_2], metric=metric).item())
dists  # [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
```

Here is one way to vectorize it:

```py
dists = cdist(vals_1, vals_2, metric=metric).diagonal()
dists  # array([0., 1., 2.])
```

It takes too much memory: it calculates all the pairwise distances:

```
array([[0., 2., 4.],
       [1., 1., 3.],
       [2., 0., 2.]])
```

and then selects only the diagonal.

##### Is there an efficient vectorized way to do this - not calculating the redundant distances?

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in or this if you really need arbitrary metrics. The only thing I'd try is taking your loopy solution and pass it through `numba` or `pythran` in a dedicated function. If it works, you only need to compile that once (with `cache=True` in the `numba` case) and reap the speed benefits on every subsequent call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the distance between the corresponding position vectors, the corresponding position operation and the operation along the axis of numpy can be vectorized well (reference to [Basic array operations](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/absolute_beginners.html#basic-array-operations)), so we can easily write the following code:

```
def euclidean(XA, XB, *, out=None):
    return np.sqrt(np.add.reduce(np.square(XA - XB), 1), out=out)
    #              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ is equivalent to np.sum but faster


def sqeuclidean(XA, XB, *, out=None):
    return np.add.reduce(np.square(XA - XB), 1, out=out)


def cityblock(XA, XB, *, out=None):
    return np.add.reduce(np.abs(XA - XB), 1, out=out)


def chebyshev(XA, XB, *, out=None):
    return np.maximum.reduce(np.abs(XA - XB), 1, out=out)
    #      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ is equivalent to np.max but faster


def hamming(XA, XB, *, out=None):
    return np.add.reduce(XA != XB, 1, out=out)


def mahalanobis(XA, XB, VI, *, out=None):
    delta = XA - XB
    return np.sqrt(np.add.reduce(delta @ VI * delta, 1), out=out)

# more functions...
```

If we need to work like `cdist`, we can refer to the implementation of it to write similar code, here are some core parts completed:

```
_METRIC_INFOS = {
    euclidean: ['euclidean', 'euclid', 'eu', 'e'],
    sqeuclidean: ['sqeuclidean', 'sqe', 'sqeuclid'],
    cityblock: ['manhattan', 'cityblock', 'cblock', 'cb', 'c'],
    chebyshev: ['chebychev', 'chebyshev', 'cheby', 'cheb', 'ch'],
    hamming: ['matching', 'hamming', 'hamm', 'ha', 'h'],
    mahalanobis: ['mahalanobis', 'mahal', 'mah']
}

_METRICS = {metric.__name__: metric for metric in _METRIC_INFOS}
_METRIC_ALIAS = {alias: metric for metric, aka in _METRIC_INFOS.items() for alias in aka}
_METRIC_NAMES = list(_METRICS)


def dist(XA, XB, metric='euclidean', *, out=None, **kwargs):
    XA = np.asarray(XA)
    XB = np.asarray(XB)

    if XA.ndim != 2:
        raise ValueError('XA must be a 2-dimensional array.')
    if XA.shape != XB.shape:
        raise ValueError('XA and XB must have the same shape.')

    if callable(metric):
        return _dist_callable(XA, XB, out=out, metric=metric, **kwargs)
    elif isinstance(metric, str):
        metric = metric.lower()
        metirc_info = _METRIC_ALIAS.get(metric, None)
        if metirc_info is not None:
            return metirc_info(XA, XB, out=out, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Unknown Distance Metric: {metric}')
    else:
        raise TypeError('2nd argument metric must be a string identifier '
                        'or a function.')


def _dist_callable(XA, XB, *, out, metirc, **kwargs):
    mA = XA.shape[0]
    if out is None:
        out = np.empty(mA)
    for i in range(mA):
        out[i] = metirc(XA[i], XB[i], **kwargs)
    return out
```

Test:

```
>>> a = np.arange(20).reshape(-1, 4)
>>> b = a[::-1]
>>> dist(a, b)
array([32., 16.,  0., 16., 32.])
>>> dist(a, b, 'cityblock')
array([64, 32,  0, 32, 64])
>>> dist(a, b, 'chebyshev')
array([16,  8,  0,  8, 16])
>>> dist(a, b, 'sqeuclidean')
array([1024,  256,    0,  256, 1024])
>>> dist(a, b, 'hamming')
array([4, 4, 0, 4, 4])
>>> dist(a, b, 'mahalanobis', VI=np.eye(a.shape[1]) * 2)
array([45.254834, 22.627417,  0.      , 22.627417, 45.254834])
```

Comment: Great! If there doesn’t exist an official implementation of it, you showed how we can implement it ourselves!

Comment: @VladimirFokow I didn't notice that broadcasting is not used here. It mainly uses the corresponding position operation and axis operation of numpy. [Broadcasting](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.broadcasting.html) is another method of vectorized array operation.